# Change fixture response in cypress for the same url with intercept

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I am trying to write a test with the new cypress 6 interceptor method ([Cypress API Intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html)). For the test I am writing I need to change the reponse of one endpoint after some action was performed.

**Expectation:**

I am calling cy.intercept again with another fixture and expect it to change all upcomming calls to reponse with this new fixture.

**Actual Behaviour:**

Cypress still response with the first fixture set for the call.

**Test Data:**

In a test project I have recreated the problem:

test.spec.js

```js
describe('testing cypress', () => {


    it("multiple responses", () => {

        cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { fixture: 'example.json' });

        // when visiting the page it makes one request to http://localhost:4200/testcall
        cy.visit('http://localhost:4200');
        cy.get('.output').should('contain.text', '111');

        // now before the button is clicked and the call is made again
        // cypress should change the response to the other fixture
        cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { fixture: 'example2.json' });

        cy.get('.button').click();
        cy.get('.output').should('contain.text', '222');
        
    });

});
```

example.json

```json
{
  "text": "111"
}
```

example2.json

```json
{
  "text": "222"
}
```

app.component.ts

```ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public text: string;

  public constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }

  public loadData(): void {
    const loadDataSubscription = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:4200/testcall').subscribe(response => {
      this.text = response.body;
      loadDataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```html
<button class="button" (click)="loadData()">click</button>

<p class="output" [innerHTML]="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Slightly clumsy, but you can use one `cy.intercept()` with a [Function routeHandler](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Intercepting-a-response), and count the calls.

Something like,

```
let interceptCount = 0;  

cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', (req) => {   
  req.reply(res => {     
    if (interceptCount === 0 ) {
      interceptCount += 1;
      res.send({ fixture: 'example.json' })
    } else {
      res.send({ fixture: 'example2.json' })
    }
  }); 
});
```

Otherwise, everything looks good in your code so I guess over-riding an intercept is not a feature at this time.

Comment: Ok I think this would be a useful feature for cy.intercept().

Thanks for your code! I have tried it and there is a minor thing missing. From intercept I get the request and with this request I can manipulate the response as you suggested. This actually works in my case now.
`let interceptCount = 0;

cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', (req) => {
  req.reply(res => {
    if (interceptCount === 0 ) {
      interceptCount += 1;
      res.send({ fixture: 'example.json' })
    } else {
      res.send({ fixture: 'example2.json' })
    }
  });
});`

Comment: Yes you're right, the `req` controls the `res`.

Comment: This does not work in circleci for some reaon. Locally it passes fine.

Answer (score 20):

As of Cypress [v7.0.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v7.0.0) released 04/05/2021, `cy.intercept()` allows over-riding.

> We introduced several breaking changes to cy.intercept().
>
> - Request handlers supplied to cy.intercept() are **now matched starting with the most recently defined request interceptor**. This allows users to override request handlers by calling cy.intercept() again.

So your example code above now works

```js
cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { fixture: 'example.json' });

// when visiting the page it makes one request to http://localhost:4200/testcall
cy.visit('http://localhost:4200');
cy.get('.output').should('contain.text', '111');

// now cypress should change the response to the other fixture
cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { fixture: 'example2.json' });

cy.get('.button').click();
cy.get('.output').should('contain.text', '222');
```

Answer (score 11):

Cypress command [cy.intercept](https://on.cypress.io/intercept) has the
`times` parameter that you can use to create intercepts that only are used N times. In your case it would be

```js
cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { 
  fixture: 'example.json',
  times: 1 
});
...
cy.intercept('http://localhost:4200/testcall', { 
  fixture: 'example2.json',
  times: 1
});
```

See the `cy.intercept` example in the Cypress recipes repo https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes#network-stubbing-and-spying

Answer (score 0):

```
const requestsCache = {};
export function reIntercept(type: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE', url, options: StaticResponse) {
    requestsCache[type + url] = options;
    cy.intercept(type, url, req => req.reply(res => {
        console.log(url, ' => ', requestsCache[type + url].fixture);
        return res.send(requestsCache[type + url]);
    }));
}
```

Make sure to clean requestsCache when needed.