# cypress use same endpoint with different response (testing http race condition)

Tags: cypress, e2e

I try to intercept two similar requests but two different responses in delay between each responses.

1. send a first request to the /endpoint with delay in response like 3000ms
2. second request to the same /endpoint with delay in response 1000ms

both requests have different response, something difficult to overwrite interceptor here

```js
        cy.intercept('POST', '/validate', (req) => {
            req.reply({
                delay: 3000,
                fixture: 'invalidData.json'
            });
        })

        cy.intercept('POST', '/validate', (req) => {
            req.reply({
                delay: 1000,
                fixture: 'validData.json'
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Gleb Bahmutov's answer here
[Change fixture response in cypress for the same url with intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69030800/16997707)

Use the `times` option to restrict how many calls the intercept will catch.

But note, the last added intercept is checked first so you probably need to reverse the order.

```js
cy.intercept({method: 'POST', url: '/validate', times: 1}, (req) => {
  req.reply({
    delay: 1000,
    fixture: 'validData.json'
  });
})

cy.intercept({method: 'POST', url: '/validate', times: 1}, (req) => {
  req.reply({
    delay: 3000,
    fixture: 'invalidData.json'
  });
})
```

---

**Example app**

```js
<script>
  setTimeout(() => {
    fetch('/validate', { method: 'POST'})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log('1st', res))
  }, 100)
  setTimeout(() => {
    fetch('/validate', { method: 'POST'})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log('2nd', res))
  }, 200)
</script>
```

Console outputs in expected order, with different fixture data

```js
2nd {data: 'valid'}
1st {data: 'invalid'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can supply an array of routeHandlers in the order you want them applied

```js
it('test the same route multiple times', () => {
  let request = 0;
  const replies = [
    {delay: 3000, fixture: 'invalidData.json'},
    {delay: 1000, fixture: 'validData.json'},
  ]
  cy.intercept('POST', '/validate', (req) => {
    req.reply(replies[request++])
  });

  cy.visit(...);

})
```

Comment: this is also working, thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gleb's [example here](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#count-intercepts-again) as a starting point. We'll be using a variable out of scope of the intercept to keep track of requests.

```js
it('some test', () => {
  let requestCount = 0;
  cy.intercept('POST', '/validate', (req) => {
    requestCount++;
    req.reply({
      delay: requestCount === 1 ? 1000 : 3000,
      fixture: requestCount === 1 ? 'validData.json' : 'invalidData.json'
    });
  });
  // rest of test
})
```

You can modify your logic to return different delays / fixtures if the ternary provided does not accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Similar requests means you can distinguish them, so do that by any property within the request.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/validate', (req) => {
  if (req.body.any.property.only.of.my.first.request === true) {
    req.reply({
      delay: 1000,
      fixture: 'validData.json'
    });
  } else {
    req.reply({
      delay: 3000,
      fixture: 'invalidData.json'
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: Not exactly, want to make it simultaneously and return response based on delay, so here first request come in 1s and 2nd request response after 3 seconds, may be something like this https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-intercept-problems/#sending-different-responses